# Image not being called Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to change the image when I click on a cell but it isn't working

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [feedsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UILabel *title = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0011];
UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0017];

image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reload.png"];
title.text = @"test";

cellClicked = YES;

[feedsTableView beginUpdates];
[feedsTableView endUpdates];

[feedsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

The title however changes.

How my image is added inside the table.

```
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 90);
    customImage.tag = 0017;
    self.customImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.customImage];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:0017];

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reload.png"];
```

UIImages aren't UIView subclasses. Notice how in your second block of code you are adding a UIImageView to the cell and not a UIImage.

Answer (score 2):

Did you know that in C (and therefore Objective-C and C++) that an integer literal with a leading `0` is octal, and not decimal.

Therefore:

```
0011 != 11
0017 != 17
```

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't make a difference as long as you continue to be consistent with using `0011` as a tag and using `0011` to get a view with that tag.

Comment: @Jasarien Does IB follow the same convention then (assuming that's where the tag has been set)?

Comment: that's another question... It depends on whether or not IB takes what's in the field literally as an integer, or parses it to integer format (thus stripping the leading zeros). Will have to test. Regardless, the question shows that the tag is set in code as `0017`.

Comment: Nope, IB parses the input and validates it on entry. Entering `0017` results in `17` being shown in the text field.

Comment: @Jasarien Seeing `0011/0017` in the code is therefore cause for concern, however I'm sure my answer doesn't answer the question completely.

Comment: Only if not used consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than add the views from the table view, why not just use a custom UITableViewCell?

That way you can avoid using tags, as you can just set up the label and image view as properties of the cell, and you avoid this whole problem.

It's also slightly more performant, as the label and image view will be reused along with the cell, rather than needing to set them up every time.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to replace the cell with a anew XIB one ? IF you know about a good tutorial or something that I could start of with that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could position your elements in code if you like. Have a look at the [customizing cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18) section in the documentation.